# How can I use sys and argparse in same python script without getting unrecognized argument error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, sys

As my title suggests, I am using sys and argparse to add command line arguments to my code.  Sys is being used to add a file path like /sample/test/etc and argparse is being used to add a separate optional functionality in my code.  My code works just fine when I use just argparse but when sys comes in the picture is when the following error shows up:

test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /sample/test/etc

The first few lines of my code I use sys to save the file path into a variable:

import sys

path = sys.argv[1]

Is there anyway I can utilize sys to record a file path while keeping my argparse which is, -r, later in the code?

Comment: By default `parse_args` uses `sys.argv[1:]` (`sys.argv[0]` is the `prog`).  So simply looking at `sys.argv[1]` doesn't change what `argparse` sees.  You can alter `sys.argv`, or pass your own list of strings as argument to `parse_args`.  Another options is to use `parse_known_args`.

Comment: I think the problem is that if argparse is not aware of the positional argument (path), it raises an error when it sees it. I'd guess the best solutions is just to handle all arguments with argparse (or suppress argparse errors).

Comment: Why doesn't your parser recognize a `path` argument?  (besides the fact that you just didn't implement it)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `sys.argv` to capture the path, you can handle both arguments with `argparse`. If you add an argument without a `-` prefix, it will be treated as a compulsory positional argument:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description')
parser.add_argument('path', help='Path')
parser.add_argument('-r', '--relative', action='store_true',
                    help='optional argument')
args = parser.parse_args()
print('path: {:}'.format(args.path))
print('relative: {:}'.format(args.relative))
```

Usage:

```
myscript.py [-h] [-r] path
```